# How can i run a set of thread groups together

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, threadgroup

I want to run a set of thread groups:

--Thread Group A
--Thread Group B
--Thread Group C
--Thread Group D

I want to Run A and B together(as in 'A' First and Then 'B') and while this is happening i want to run C and D together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you can use in Thread Group the scheduler checkbox.

And fill duration.

Then configure startup delay to get what you want.

Comment: But i want A and C to start together

Comment: Put same startup delay

Comment: The Scenario is : ThreadGroup A, logins as User1 only once and ThreadGroup B have the Test Samples for User1 with multiple threads.

ThreadGroup C, logins as User2 only once and ThreadGroup D have the Test Samples for User2 with multiple threads.

I want to run these Test Samples of User1 and User2 simultaneously

Comment: Is this another question ? If so you should accept this one and start a new question , please format it better than in comment so that it is readable. For now in comment I don't understand what you want to do. thx